# Data Studio Connector with Dynamic Schema

Tags: google-apps-script, salesforce, looker-studio

I am building a Salesforce Data Studio Connector for the company I work for.  I want the user to select the Object from the calling interface (there will be 5 objects).  How do I dynamically call the different schema and data based on the selected Object.  I tried several different ways, one using a global variable, but the variable will no persist in the getData() call.

Comment: Hi, Were you find how to do this?